# How to prevent common.css and other styles from being loaded?

Tags: css

I set the apex:page parameter standardStylesheets="false". But some stylesheets are still being loaded and affecting display, such as common.css:

https://www.evernote.com/shard/s167/sh/e1b6d6b5-d67d-4d3c-861b-1e8e91e2f94e/8233ccc5d653fc93eebd5b8a92526c23

How do I prevent them from loading?

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution. I don't think we need the CSS, so I disabled it on page load, as per this article: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12857734/removing-the-css-file. You can also remove it entirely with .remove().

Luckily, all the CSS files are being loaded via  tag, which all have the class "user":

```
  $("link.user").each(function(){
    $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
  });
```

Comment: Is there a chance that you've got development mode enabled for some users which is why it's only happening for them?

Comment: I think I was incorrect that the CSS is only being loaded for admins--it's being loaded for everyone, which I verified by opening the site in Private Browsing window. I edited my answer above.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try to set `sidebar="false"` and `showHeader="false"` with `standardStyleSheets="false"` in `apex:page`. This will show up a balnk page and it will a plain HTML page without any standard style of salesforce.

Comment: I already have these attributes in apex:page. This stops the main stylesheets from being loaded, but certain stylesheets continue to be loaded against our will, such as common.css. The answer I posted above is the only solution I found.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same problem tonight. My set up was that my page called a template via `<apex:composition>`. My page had the relevant `sidebar` and `showHeader` and `standardStyleSheets` all set to `false`, but `common.css` was still getting included.

The resolution was to set all of the above parameters to false in the page template **as well as** the page you're calling the template in, as the template is a page too.